# how to get desired datetime format

Tags: c#

i want to generate current date and time in a format like this  **Mon, 10/08/12 12:29:39** . But when i used a code shown below

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

i am getting like **10/8/2012 12:29:39 PM** , but i actually want a format like **Mon, 10/08/12 12:29:39** , what change in this code i can use to get the desired output.
I did this code also ,but didnt success

```
string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";    // Use this format
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString(format));
```

Comment: "but didnt success" is not a good enough description of what happened. Ideally, write a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Include the desired behaviour, and the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("ddd, MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string format = "ddd, MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to provide the `Culture` (or the `InvariantCulture`) as a formatting parameter. Otherwise it will default to the `UI culture` which might not always provide the format that you expect.

```
string format = time.ToString("ddd, MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should read this page for the future

Custom Date and Time Format Strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for all detail datetime

```
string inp;
DateTime inpdate = DateTime.ParseExact(inp, "dd/mm/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

and u too use this code for with out time

```
ret = pc.ToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(inp.Split('/')[2]), Convert.ToInt32(inp.Split('/')[1]), Convert.ToInt32(inp.Split('/')[0]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format either by using one of the built in Methods for example:

```
.ToShortDateTimeString();
```

or specifying a string format in the parameter of the .ToString() method.

Example:

```
.ToString("hh/MM/yyyy");
```

you can find all the available string formats on the MSDN page, or if you simply google it.